# Creating Bell states (a question from tutorial)

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, bell-basis

I was going through a Quantum Computation lecture series on YouTube given by Umesh Vazirani. There in Lecture 6.3 he talks about creating a Bell state using a Hadamard and CNOT gate. He seems to be using |0⟩ and |1⟩. Is he talking about measuring a qubit in 0-1 basis and then using the qubits that gave 0 as a result for the |0⟩. Here is an image for reference.[image: The screenshot of the lecture.]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. I am a little bit confused by your question. Could you please be more specific? Do you have a problem with understanding how to create different Bell states? Or outcome of measurement?

Comment: I was having a problem trying to understand what |0⟩ meant as I thought qubits were always said to be in terms of probability. But, after a little bit of google now i understood it. So, I'm closing this question now. Thank you for your help anyways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no measurement in the picture; the picture shows how to construct 4 Bell states $|\Phi^+\rangle$, $|\Phi^-\rangle$, $|\Psi^+\rangle$ and $|\Psi^-\rangle$ using Hadamard-CNOT circuit.